# Velocity initialization failed with Tomcat security manager ON

Tags: java, velocity, tomcat8

I am using Velocity 1.7 and Tomcat 8. I have this code:

```
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.setProperty(Velocity.RUNTIME_LOG_LOGSYSTEM_CLASS,NullLogChute.class.getName());
try {
    Velocity.init(props);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine when I start tomcat without security manager, but when I start Tomcat with security manager, I catch this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at java.io.Reader.(Reader.java:78)
>    at java.io.InputStreamReader.(InputStreamReader.java:97)
>       at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:542)
>       at org.apache.commons.collections.ExtendedProperties.load(ExtendedProperties.java:518)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.setDefaultProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:416)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:628)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:261)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:646)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:226)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:97)

How can I add the permission in catalina.policy to make velocity work?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

---

Velocity is trying to load its default properties file from the following classpath file: `org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties`.

So you must grant your webapp (or more specifically the Velocity jar) a read java.io.FilePermission permission towards:

```
your-velocity-engine.jar!org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/velocity.properties
```

And you'll also need the same permission towards:

```
your-velocity-engine.jar!org/apache/velocity/runtime/defaults/directive.properties
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will try that.

Comment: We granted java.io.FilePermission for the entire folder of velocity.jar, and it's working now. Thanks again.